# CreateDIBSection is throwing, when trying to create cursor on Win

Tags: c++, windows, createdibsection

I am trying to create Cursor from png, and `CreateDIBSection()` is throwing.

Follwoing is the snippet of code:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
void* lpBits = NULL;
HBITMAP  hBitmap;
try
{
 hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(
  hdc,
  (BITMAPINFO*)&bi,
  0,
  &lpBits,
  NULL,
  (DWORD)0);
}

ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

As `CreateDIBSection` is throwing, the code to release DC is not getting executed. can you please let me know the possible issue behind this?

Comment: have u initialized  BITMAPINFO properly ?

Comment: BITMAPV5HEADER bi    = { };

 bi.bV5Size   = sizeof bi;
 bi.bV5Width   = lWidth;
 bi.bV5Height  = lHeight; 
 bi.bV5Planes  = 1;
 bi.bV5BitCount  = 32;
 bi.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;

 
 // alpha format for Windows XP.
 bi.bV5AlphaMask  = 0xFF000000;
 bi.bV5RedMask  = 0x00FF0000;
 bi.bV5GreenMask  = 0x0000FF00;
 bi.bV5BlueMask  = 0x000000FF;

I have used these values.

Answer (score 0):

You should make structure zeroed out:

ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER));

Try out this link , it may help you :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318876